# Android - Google API Speech Recognition - Second execution of Thread fails

Tags: java, android, multithreading, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

i'm trying to write a speech assistant for android based on this example:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/Speech/app/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/android/speech/VoiceRecorder.java

From time to time i need to shutdown the speech recognition to play some audio files (since i don't want them to be captured). The first round everything works well, but when i try to start the speech recognition the second time, i get the following error:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.lang.ThreadGroup.addUnstarted()' on a null object reference
        at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:411)
        at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:469)
        at com.vivai.de.vivaivoice.tools.tools.continuous.speechRecognition.AudioRecorder.start(AudioRecorder.java:96)
        at com.vivai.de.vivaivoice.tools.tools.continuous.AudioServiceManager.recordAudio(AudioServiceManager.java:174)
        at com.vivai.de.vivaivoice.tools.tools.continuous.AudioServiceManager.run(AudioServiceManager.java:123)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
```

The following lines produce the error. It is thrown when new Thread() gets called.

```
public void start() {
        // Stop recording if it is currently ongoing.
        stop();
        // Try to create a new recording session.
        mAudioRecord = createAudioRecord();
        if (mAudioRecord == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot instantiate VoiceRecorder");
        }
        // Start recording.
        mAudioRecord.startRecording();
        // Start processing the captured audio.
        ProcessVoice processVoice = new ProcessVoice();
        mThread = new Thread(processVoice);
        mThread.start();
        Log.i(TAG, "started");
    }
```

I think that the error is thrown, because it doesn't want to execute the same Thread/Runnable twice, but i create a hole new Object so that shouldn't be a problem? I already tried to write a wrapper class from which i create a new object from, but that didnt' help either.
Anyone got an idea on how to deal with that issue or how to passby?
Thanks in advance for any help.